Flask API Pytest Unit Tests Failing Due to Pyodbc
I’m having some issues with using Pytest. My Flask API uses pyodbc to talk to a MSSQL server db. The API runs in a Docker container and I'm running this on my Mac.
I have a unit test for a healthcheck (root level ie localhost:5000/) route that is as follows:
from app import app

def test_healthcheck(self):
    """
    Test the healthcheck endpoint
    EXPECTS: A 200 status code and the string "Healthcheck"
    """
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        response = self.app.get("/")
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert response.data, b"Healthcheck"

And my project is structured as follows:
myproject
| app.py
| — api/
       | — routes/
       | — utils/
                | db.py
                | helpers.py

| — tests/
         | test_healthcheck.py

When I run python3 -m pytest, I get the following error:
ERROR tests/test_healthcheck.py - pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

The error logs show the pyodbc error stems from the pyodbc.connect() line my db.py util file, which is a class-based abstraction of the db operations.
class DB:
    """
    Class to abstract out MS SQL Server DB operations
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn_str = os.getenv("CONN_STR")
        if not self.conn_str:
            raise RuntimeError("Missing 'CONN_STR' env var")
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect(self.conn_str)

But I have pyodbc installed on my local machine, and when I run the API in Docker, I don't encounter any pyodbc issues.
In case this helps, app.py is as follows:
import logging
from flask import Flask
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from api.routes.healthcheck import bp as health_bp
from api.routes.generate import bp as generate_bp

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(health_bp)
app.register_blueprint(generate_bp)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger("werkzeug").setLevel(logging.INFO)

I see the Pytest docs talking about a conftest.py file, but this seems to rely on the factory app pattern, which this app does not. Do I need conftest? And how do I get this pyodbc error to go away?

If you want to make unit tests for database, its better to create methods and mock the connection to test what it is doing, or if it is not specific to sql server, you can use in memoery data base like conn_str = 'Driver=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=:memory:'
